# Добавить свой объект Ext

Tags: javascript, modx, extjs

Как добавить к полученным от сервера данным свой объект? Например, где id = 0, а name = 'None'

```
modExtra.combo.Categories = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config, {
        name: 'category',
        hiddenName: 'category',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'id',
        url: modExtra.config.connector_url,
        baseParams: {
            action: 'mgr/categories/getlist'
        },
        fields: ['id', 'name']
    });

    modExtra.combo.Categories.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};
Ext.extend(modExtra.combo.Categories, MODx.combo.ComboBox);
Ext.reg('modextra-combo-categories', modExtra.combo.Categories);
```

UPD Сделал так:

```
modExtra.combo.Categories = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config, {
        name: 'category',
        hiddenName: 'category',
        displayField: 'name',
        id: 'myCountrySearchBox',
        valueField: 'id',
        url: modExtra.config.connector_url,
        baseParams: {
            action: 'mgr/categories/getlist'
        },
        fields: ['id', 'name']
    });

    modExtra.combo.Categories.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
/* после загрузки ComboBox присваиваем объекту новые значения в конец списка */
    this.store.on('load', function() {
        this.store.add(new this.store.recordType({
            id: null,
            name: _('modextra_combobox_empty')
        }, 0));
    }, this);
};
Ext.extend(modExtra.combo.Categories, MODx.combo.ComboBox);
Ext.reg('modextra-combo-categories', modExtra.combo.Categories);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делаю обычно так:

```
baseParams: {
    action: 'mgr/categories/getlist',
    addall: 1
},
```

в процессоре `'mgr/categories/getlist'` добавляю

```
public function afterIteration(array $list) {
    $addall = $this->getProperty('addall');
    if (!empty($addall)) {
        $list_all = array(
            array(
                'id' => 0, 
                'name' => $this->modx->lexicon('modextra.combo.all'),
            )
        );
        $list = array_merge($list_all, $list);;
    }
    return $list;
}
```

и в переводы добавляю

```
$_lang['modextra.combo.all'] = 'None';
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш вариант! Сделал так:
    this.store.on('load', function() {
        this.store.add(new this.store.recordType({
            id: null,
            name: _('modextra_combobox_empty')
        }, 0));
    }, this);

Answer (score 1):

В Ext есть хранилища, например, JsonStore. Они позволяют добавлять значения/изменять/удалять. Попробуйте загрузить список в store, потом добавить значение, а выпадающий список перенастроить на это хранилище.

Деталей не помню, т.к. давно работал с ExtJs 3.

Либо с сервера вернуть уже подходящий список.

З.Ы. Насколько помню, Ext за кулисами при таком объявлении как у Вас создает простенький ArrayStore. У него должны быть события на окончание загрузки. Возможно, получится к нему привязаться и добавить требуемое значение.